# How can I restrict the relation so the tables just join when is a relationship?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I made a relations (1:n) between 2 tables. Not every element from fathers layer have connection with elements from child layer. The connection is made between 'Tipo de Estrutura' Field and 'Est' Field like shown below.

[image: Creation of the Relationship]

[image: Table of content (1) Fathers Layer (2) Child Layer]

The relation is made correctly. My problem is with the elements that have no relation (Example 'Rocha'). When I open the 'identify feature' of 'Rocha' Element is shown a relationship table with no elements. It is possible to only show relation when exist or hide this connection?

[image]